# How to deploy Preprocessing Code with Vertex AI Endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have deployed a model in Vertex AI Endpoint and I am able to get the prediction by passing preprocessed features vector.

I want also to deploy preprocess code alongside the model.
How to wrap or deploy preprocessing logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a Cloud Function or some similar type of setup to transform the inputs. This can be hosted on a server etc. It can also be deployed to an endpoint. In any case, the transformation will be custom code and you will have to pass the requests there before sending them to vertex ai; but vertex ai will only accept them once processed.

You can create a Cloud Function [1] that preprocesses the data and sends it to your custom model [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http

[2] https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-custom-models

Please let me know if it helps. If not could you please provide me with the following information.

What type of architecture are you using?
Did you follow any documentation?

Comment: To add to this answer, you could also possibly be interested in [this introduction](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/introduction) to Vertex pipelines in order to process your data.